# Do "spare bedroom" and "extra bedroom" mean the same thing?

Tags: word-usage, meaning, adjectives

> a. extra bedroom
>
> b. spare bedroom

Is there any difference in the meanings?

Comment: What's the context? I can't think of any differences off the top of my head, but in the context you intend, someone might notice one is better than the other.

Comment: I've never heard it used in that way. A _spare bedroom_ is one not currently occupied and therefore available for a guest; an _extra  bedroom_ would be one added to the house, either by altering the building or converting a room from another function.

Comment: Can you provide a context in which you want to use "extra bedroom" and perhaps explain why "spare bedroom" is no good.

Comment: @KateBunting - Cambridge says "If something is spare, it is available to use because it is extra:"

Comment: @MichaelWokeHarvey - Well, yes - but does anyone call their guest bedroom 'the extra room'?

Comment: @KateBunting we call ours the 'prisoners room' because it used to have a dodgy door handle and my sister got trapped and had to to bang to be released. I guess it is the spare bedroom.

Comment: In AmE, spare and extra are synonymous in this context.

Comment: Why do people downvote this type of question? It is perfectly reasonable that an ELL might not know this.

Comment: @Lambie quick Google for e.g. "spare meaning".

Answer (score 3):

In the absence of more context, there is no clear difference in meaning. As the [comment](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/305712/do-spare-bedroom-and-extra-bedroom-mean-the-same-thing#comment571972_305712) by Kate Bunting suggests, an **extra** bedroom might be an addition to a house, but it might simply be a room not currently in use, or not in use as a bedroom.

More context might well clarify the intended usage.

Comment: Thank you all so much. I think things are clear now. I think I used 'extra' myself meaning 'spare' and then began wondering if I had chosen that word correctly. I changed it to 'spare' to be on the safe side. But the question was in my head!

Answer (score 2):

One meaning of extra is something additional to the required or usual amount. In some sense, an unused room might be extra. It might be extra to the needs of the family who lived in a house.  If you were buying a house and you needed two bedrooms for your family, and the house had three, the third one might be extra.

Spare has the meaning of something kept in reserve for the purpose of satisfying an unplanned need. A spare tire is kept to deal with unexpected tire damage. A spare bedroom is kept for the use of unexpected guests. (Heh. Keeping it in reserve means you expect them at some level. They are *expected* unexpected guests. If they were *really* unexpected you would not prepare for them.)

So extra and spare refer to different reasons why something is currently not in use.